# Amazon Cloud Drive invalid scope

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, oauth2client

I am trying to authenticate to the cloud drive API using OAuth2. The scope string query parameter in the URL is:

scope=clouddrive%3Awrite+clouddrive%3Aread_all

The response that I get is:

http://localhost/?error_description=lwa-invalid-parameter-bad-scope&state=1449953115&error=invalid_scope

My security profile is already whitelisted.

If the scope is clouddrive%3Awrite only then it works.

My Questions and comments:
Why is the write and read_all scope invalid?
Would the write scope allow reading as well? 
The Getting started example here: https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/experience/cloud-drive/content/restful-api-getting-started uses both write and read_all scope in the example.

Answer (score 0):

My client_secret had a typo! It is working now.